Keycloak Angular Integration - No Longer Setting Auth Token After Upgrade to Angular v18/Keycloak Angular 16.0.1
I recently upgrade an an Angular app to V18. This app uses "keycloak-angular" for SSO; as such, with the Angular v18 upgrade, I also upgraded keycloak-angular to v16.0.1. However, after the upgrade, the authorization token is no longer being set.
My configuration is pretty much straight out of the docs and had been functioning well until this upgrade.
In my app.module:, I have added the service to my providers
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: initializeKeycloak,
      multi: true,
      deps: [KeycloakService],
    },

where initializeKeycloak is defined as:
function initializeKeycloak(keycloak: KeycloakService) {


  return () =>
    keycloak.init({
      config: {
        url: 'https:/xxxx',
        realm: 'xxx',
        clientId: 'xxx',
      },
      initOptions: {
        onLoad: 'login-required',
        enableLogging: !environment.production,
        silentCheckSsoRedirectUri:
          window.location.origin + '/assets/silent-check-sso.html',
      },
  
    });
}

I even added the follow to the initializeKeycloak function for troubleshooting, but it does not appear as "shouldAddToken" is even being called:
  shouldAddToken: (request) => {
    const { method, url } = request;
    console.log(request);
    return true;
  }

